# Expect script for ssh connection with password and additional operations

Tags: shell, ssh, expect

I found the following script which gives me the possibility to go to a server without manually type in a required password.
Sadly I don't know how to execute commands after the connection is made :(

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@server
expect "assword:"
send "pw123\r"
interact
#the following is not executed anymore
cd /tmp/
```

The cd /tmp/ command is not executed, does someone know how to do this ?
I don't care about security :)
Key-based authentication is not an option.

Edit:
Ok, I found a solution that fits my needs:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn user@server
expect "assword:"
send "pw123\r"
expect "> " { send "cd /tmp\r" }
interact
```

The expect "> " has to be like your prompt.

Comment: I recommend using SSH key based authentication. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

Answer (score 0):

After the connection is made, you are in the shell of the remote host to which you connected through the script. So to execute any command you will have to execute command manually on the command prompt.

If you want only to execute the command on the remote server automatically without need for ssh then you can use the below command.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

#Changed here
spawn ssh user@server "cd /tmp && ls"
expect "password:"
send "pw123\r"
interact
```